# Create tree of characters

Tags: java, string, recursion, methods, tree

I have to create a tree in this way: take a string, using the first characters as root. The left/right son will be the tree create whit the substring containing minor/major characters (using alphabetical order) of the root and so on. My problem is the recursive call that does not work. Any suggestion? made myself clear? I hope so...
Example:

```
input: hello
output:    
    h
   / \
  e   l
     / \
    l   o
```

any advice on how to improve is accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a copy-paste error. Instead of `node.setLeft(rightChild);` should be `node.setRight(rightChild);`

Comment: Thank you very much! I was going crazy... now it works. if you have other tips to improve the code, please tell me.